# How to customize facebook login button using "fblogin" php?

Tags: php, facebook

In my website I am using using the facebook login button. By using fblogin its rendering default facebook login button. But I want to keep my own button instead of default facebook button. (Am not using javascript sdk).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php sdk then you can have your own button with link to the facebook login url

```
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl() // which will give the login url
```

then just link that with the image/button

```
echo "<a href='$loginurl' style='text-decoration:none'>
<img src='path/to/image' style='border:0;'></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Javascript SDK to authenticate easily.  You just need to call FB.login from a click event on a dom element.  Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="doLogin();return false;">Custom Login Button</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: '**yourAppId', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml : true });

  function doLogin() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
            alert('User: ' + response.name);
            alert('Full details: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
          }
        );
      }
    } , {perms:''}); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```